# Did all the human hosts of the Mind Flayer die in Stranger Things 3?

Tags: ending, stranger-things

At the end of *Stranger Things* season 3, did all those people that the Mind Flayer took as hosts - Heather, Tom, Mrs. Driscoll and others - die together with the monster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all characters who became the ‘flayed’ were [melted](https://youtu.be/xpNcs3RtB-Q) and became part of the Meat Monster.

Comment: Is there any evidence for that? Cause as far as I remember, it wasn't really explained/shown.

Comment: Episode 3x06 the mind flayer merges with the flayed, except Billy, who dies later. Heather is the first to melt, watch the show again or click the link.

Comment: Tom and Bruce are also the hospital monster...but that joins the main meat monster anyways